# Static Content Serving Not Working In Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
app.use(express.static('../../www'))
})

app.listen(8080)
```

according to docs this should work but it just returns a page of garbled text

Comment: So when you go to http://localhost:8080/, what do you want to be returned? The file `../../www/index.html`?

Comment: it turns out you need an absolute path so (__dirname + '../../../www') did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use `path` module to join the current folder and relative path to an absolute path.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../../www')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('done'); 
});

app.listen(8080);
```

As @bulkan comments, you use `/style.css` to access `www/style.css`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `app.use(express.static('../../www'));` outside of the `app.get` like so;

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('../../www'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.send('done'); 
});

app.listen(8080);
```

http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use

Comment: but that way i cannot get the www/ folder on the route

Comment: With this code, if you have a file `../../www/style.css` the route to it is `/style.css`.